# Android: Failed to open a socket

Tags: android, mqtt, hivemq

i wanted to create a simple program that sends a simple message using the MQTT protocol and specifically the HiveMQ library in Android , here is what i have

```
package com.example.mqtt;

import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.MqttClient;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.datatypes.MqttQos;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.mqtt3.Mqtt3AsyncClient;
import com.hivemq.client.mqtt.mqtt3.Mqtt3BlockingClient;

import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    TextView textview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        final String host = "7f182d708d6041f88d49cffa1aae6f6d.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud";

        btn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Mqtt3BlockingClient client= MqttClient.builder()
                    .useMqttVersion3()
                    .serverHost(host)
                    .serverPort(8883)
                    .sslWithDefaultConfig()
                    .buildBlocking();

            client.connect();

            client.publishWith()
                    .topic("test")
                    .qos(MqttQos.AT_MOST_ONCE)
                    .payload(UTF_8.encode("Hello"))
                    .send();

            client.disconnect();
        });
    }
}
```

when i try to run it i get the exception

```
 Failed to open a socket.
```

here is the complete log

```
2022-06-01 17:29:11.395 21068-21068/com.example.mqtt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mqtt, PID: 21068
    com.hivemq.client.mqtt.exceptions.ConnectionFailedException: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to open a socket.
    Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to open a socket.
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.newSocket(NioSocketChannel.java:71)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.<init>(NioSocketChannel.java:88)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.<init>(NioSocketChannel.java:81)
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.netty.NettyEventLoopProvider.$r8$lambda$Vsx8-5aKZJgk81sYm310N7J4yic(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.netty.NettyEventLoopProvider$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.newChannel(Unknown Source:0)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:310)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:155)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:148)
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.mqtt.handler.connect.MqttConnAckSingle.connect(MqttConnAckSingle.java:91)
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.mqtt.handler.connect.MqttConnAckSingle.subscribeActual(MqttConnAckSingle.java:68)
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3666)
        at io.reactivex.Single.blockingGet(Single.java:2869)
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.mqtt.MqttBlockingClient.connect(MqttBlockingClient.java:99)
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.mqtt.mqtt3.Mqtt3BlockingClientView.connect(Mqtt3BlockingClientView.java:77)
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.mqtt.mqtt3.Mqtt3BlockingClientView.connect(Mqtt3BlockingClientView.java:70)
        at com.example.mqtt.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$0(MainActivity.java:40)
        at com.example.mqtt.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7509)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7486)
        at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29254)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7886)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Operation not permitted
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:420)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:413)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.<init>(SocketChannelImpl.java:130)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:60)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.newSocket(NioSocketChannel.java:69)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.<init>(NioSocketChannel.java:88) 
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.<init>(NioSocketChannel.java:81) 
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.netty.NettyEventLoopProvider.$r8$lambda$Vsx8-5aKZJgk81sYm310N7J4yic(Unknown Source:2) 
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.netty.NettyEventLoopProvider$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.newChannel(Unknown Source:0) 
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:310) 
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:155) 
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:148) 
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.mqtt.handler.connect.MqttConnAckSingle.connect(MqttConnAckSingle.java:91) 
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.mqtt.handler.connect.MqttConnAckSingle.subscribeActual(MqttConnAckSingle.java:68) 
        at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3666) 
        at io.reactivex.Single.blockingGet(Single.java:2869) 
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.mqtt.MqttBlockingClient.connect(MqttBlockingClient.java:99) 
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.mqtt.mqtt3.Mqtt3BlockingClientView.connect(Mqtt3BlockingClientView.java:77) 
        at com.hivemq.client.internal.mqtt.mqtt3.Mqtt3BlockingClientView.connect(Mqtt3BlockingClientView.java:70) 
        at com.example.mqtt.MainActivity.lambda$onCreate$0(MainActivity.java:40) 
        at com.example.mqtt.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7509) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7486) 
        at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29254) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7886)
```

does anybody know what i am doing wrong and how i can solve this?

any help would be apreciated <3

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException.

Comment: yea, you are right, i implementedd a thread and this code is now running in a different thread but i still got the same error message

Answer (score 0):

[Connecting to HiveMQ Cloud](https://console.hivemq.cloud/clients/java-hivemq?uuid=18b93f452b8445ba86ac0ec6d2228eb9) requires simple auth with a `username` and `password` properly encoded, something like this:

```
    //define your host, username and password
    final String host = "7f182d708d6041f88d49cffa1aae6f6d.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud";
    final String username = "<your-user>";
    final String password = "<your-password>";
...
...
...
        //connect to HiveMQ Cloud with TLS and username/pw
        client.connectWith()
                .simpleAuth()
                .username(username)
                .password(UTF_8.encode(password))
                .applySimpleAuth()
                .send();
```